# How can I set a value based on its sibling value in a JS object?

Tags: javascript, object

I want to do some localization by externalizing string and having some strings use other parts of the text object below. But I find that I can't refer to the object that it is part of. Is there is a way around this?

```
var text = {greeting: "hi", fullGreeting: text.greeting + " sir"}
```

Comment: I am so confused with what you're asking that I've flagged your question as **unclear what you're asking**. Please elaborate on exactly what you're after.

Comment: the duplicate was helpful, thank you. but I don't understand the top answer of why it has to include "return this". isn't that init function just adding a key/value pair to the object? that's it's whole purpose, why does it have to return anything?